# What is generally considered to be standard practice for job advert deadlines?

Tags: job-search, applications

A vacancy was advertised with no application deadline and the day after I had submitted my application I was advised that the vacancy had now been filled. This leads me to believe that applicants were being interviewed whilst the job advert was still active, meaning that any time I had spent putting togeher my application for this vacancy was wasted.

Is this a common practice and if so how can I mitigate against it? Or is there something to this process that I do not understand?

I was always under the impression that applicants are considered only when the deadline has passed to give everybody a fair chance in succeeding to the next stages.

Comment: It's nice that they got back to you and let you know promptly.

Comment: they could have not informed me that the vacancy had now been filled that is true.

Comment: And they often don't.

Comment: maybe things need to change?

Comment: @cinameng good luck in getting all companies to change...

Comment: not all companies need to change. I would never pool candidates before a deadline in the interest of fairness to all prospective candidates but then again I work in an industry that has a skills shortage so it's in my interests to do that.

Comment: thanks for the reply Joe. Yes, fill the vacancy as soon as is possible seems to be the generally considered approach that I have experianced too and my feeling on this is that you may not always actually find the best candidate doing this even though at the time you may have thought so.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere this is a really intresting perspective. I wonder whether staff rentention and attritional rates would be significalty improved if companies thought longer  and harder about how they might work towards finding the best candidate rather than just simply trying to fill a role by a deadline so they can say that they tried.

Comment: @cinameng I work in government, where it is standard to keep recruitment open for the full advertised period and assess all applicants rather than just taking the first good one. This has its good points, but it also makes the process slower and less flexible, and presents the risk that by the time we make an offer to our "best" candidate they may have already been snapped up by somebody else with a faster recruitment process. Different situations call for different methods.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent thanks, that is interesting. Is there any attempt to engage with candidates throughout the process to keep them interested whilst the advertisement remains open to others or do they only recieve an intial response once the deadline for applicants has passed?

Comment: The company's goal to hire a good candidate. "Fairness" to all applicants is not an issue important or even relevant to the hiring company as long as they are not engaging in illegal discrimination and their system gets good hires and is not perceived as disrespectful to the populace at large.

Comment: @cinameng It probably varies by agency. For the panels I've been on, applicants submitted a written app via web form and immediately get an automated acknowledgement. We'd start reviewing applications once the deadline closes (not as they come in) and once the shortlist for the next stage is finalised, we'd let everybody know. Typically about 2-4 weeks after close of applications, but it depends on how many we get and how long it takes - we aim to be pretty thorough in those assessments.

Comment: @cinameng Only time I can think of that we've contacted a candidate in between them submitting and us deciding whether to take them through to the next stage was when somebody submitted two different applications for the same job and we needed to confirm that they really were the same person rather than two similar people, and then choose which of the two apps to evaluate. OTOH, candidates are able to contact us with questions etc. at any time in the process, and some do - more often before submitting the application, but occasionally to check how it's going.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this a common practice and if so how can I mitigate against it?

Every company will handle this differently.  There is nothing that you can do to mitigate against this.

Keep in mind that before a vacancy is publicly advertised, the company may have already advertised internally and interviewed several internal candidates.

All you can do is apply to the positions that you are interested in.  If the company has not already found a good candidate and your application looks appealing, you have a chance to be considered.

Comment: thanks, this is a reasonable response. I guess what I was getting at is, how can I a maximise my time and not bother applying to those adverts that may look appealing but offer me a reduced chance to being a successfull applicant as their process is skewed in favour of those that applly earlier. The obvious response to that is to say well don't apply to any that are about to close however I would then potentially be ruling out potential employers who do in fact have a fair process of only pooling after the deadline.

Comment: @cinameng Personally, if I am looking for a new job I would apply to any position that looks promising regardless of the closing date.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere haha "so it goes" sums my feelings up nicely on this issue. In this particular case I would say that I had spent just over an hour putting together an application. I have a shortlist of over 100 vacancies that I'd like to consider putting in an application for and I would like to a) know who I am applyting to before I submit any application and b) tailor my application to the industry/role/position. If I could eliminate any organisations that are happy to waste peoples time by bending the process to their own favour I would.

Comment: @cinameng Consider a new perspective in that time and effort that you spend on applying for positions, researching companies, filling out applications, and so on. Maybe you spent an hour or three on the job application process this time, but in the end, you got rejected. Instead of viewing those 3 hours as 3 wasted hours, look at it as 3 hours spent to make yourself better in the "applying for a job" task. Applying for a job is also a skill that you need to practice to get good at, just like the other skills you need to perform for any job that you'll eventually be hired for.

Answer (score 11):

> A vacancy was advertised with no application deadline and the day after I had submitted my application I was advised that the vacancy had now been filled.

Generally if there's no deadline advertised it means a *de facto* "deadline" of "until we fill the position", it doesn't make much sense not to fill the position as soon as a suitable candidate is available - not only is that delaying you filling the organisations need to have someone doing that role but you risk being gazumped for good candidates.

> This leads me to believe that applicants were being interviewed whilst the job advert was still active, meaning that any time I had spent putting together my application for this vacancy was wasted.

Not automatically - if none of the candidates they were interviewing had turned out to be suitable then your application would have been next up as it were. Job applications by their nature are **always** speculative, you've got no guarantee of a return on your "investment".

> Is this a common practice and if so how can I mitigate against it? Or is there something to this process that I do not understand?

It will vary from industry to industry but in my experience it's very common in private companies.

> I was always under the impression that applicants are considered only when the deadline has passed to give everybody a fair chance in succeeding to the next stages.

Certainly this is common when there *is* a deadline - but as mentioned above sometimes there just.. isn't one. Even where there is one and the decision won't be made until after the deadline those who get applications in early will still potentially be considered earlier - and a good candidate there might well gain something of an advantage by setting a comparator for later ones.

Sometimes an organisation will find a standout application well in advance of the deadline they've set and fill the position early. Certainly if that were to happen and they failed to take the advert down that's something of a *faux pas* on their part and it's understandably frustrating for an applicant who was mislead as a result but it's not the end of the world.

Remember that *both* parties in the recruitment process are attempting to optimise for their needs, **not** for "fairness". If there's a deadline it's usually so the organisation can batch reviewing/interviewing the applicants in one go, if there isn't it's so they can cast a wide net while ensuring that they can hire as soon as a suitable candidate is available. Sure there *might* be a better candidate about to click that "submit application" button the next day, but then there might an *even better* candidate about to do the same the day after that.

As a candidate you're going to optimise for you getting a suitable position as soon as possible - so if there's an advert without a deadline you apply as soon as you can. And if there is a deadline you might reasonably bet that it's a better strategy to spend that extra time polishing the application and submitting closer to the deadline.

If the possibility of missing out as you've experienced here really bothers you then you could always decline to apply to any job posting without a deadline - but I think doing so is only going to serve to cut you off from a large number of opportunities.

Answer (score 4):

This is going to be highly dependent on the country, industry, and job as well as the hiring climate.  In the US in 2022, for example, it would generally only be government jobs and a handful of very large and usually rather bureaucratic organizations that would wait to interview any candidate until after an application deadline had passed.  But other countries and industries likely have different norms (the search process for Chief of Neurosurgery at Big City Hospital will be different than the search for Crew Member at the local McDonalds).

Realistically, there is no such thing as a process that is fair to every candidate.  If I advertise a job position with a 1 month application deadline and don't interview good candidates as resumes come in, that's going to be unfair to candidates that apply early.  They will have almost certainly accepted another offer long before I call them to schedule an interview or at least they'll be in advanced discussions with other companies.  If I interview good candidates as resumes come in, there may be someone that applies just before the deadline whose effort is wasted.  Of course, it's also possible that the company has many similar roles and will consider your application for one of those roles when it opens up in a week.

There is also, realistically, no such thing as the best candidate.  Interview processes are inherently noisy-- you're getting a 1 or 2 hour sample of what someone can produce when they're on their best behavior and in a relatively unknown and stressful environment.  If you're realistic, you can hope to differentiate between "bad", "good", and "great" candidates but it is unlikely that you can meaningfully predict which of the great candidates would actually perform best.  If you batch all the applicants, you'll probably have to find some criteria to order several great candidates but that's likely to be a lot of work for little or no marginal gain.  You're better off as a company hiring the first great candidate that walks through the door.

Most job sites will let you filter job posts to only show those posted in the past X days.  If you're concerned about applying to positions where the company might already be extending offers, only apply to positions that were posted in the last week or so.  Of course, this will depend on how specialized your skillset is-- if companies generally spend months searching for someone with your specialized skillset before they find a candidate, you'd want to look at somewhat older job posts.

Comment: thank you for your considered response. I'm in the UK and we have a serious issue with recruitment in my industry for a number of reasons which could be why I want to take a slightly different perspective on this particualr issue if I can.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere there are not enough good applicants out there. The required solution is something that increses the both the quality and quantity of the candidate pool rather than just one or the other. Putting an applicant in a situation where they can be wasting time applying for a job that they can never obtain doesn't seem to really work towards either of those objectives.

Comment: @cinameng - If there are not enough good applicants, all the more reason for a company to hire the first good one that walks in the door.  If they wait to interview until they take the ad down, all the good candidates that applied are likely to have been given an offer from another company.  It is unlikely that you are going to increase the quality and quantity of the candidate pool and have the quality candidates you want still available to accept an offer all at the same time.  As with everything, there are trade-offs.

Comment: @cinameng You may be interested in reading about the [Secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem). Of course, that's presented in a very theoretical way, but mathematically speaking, it's provable that the optimal method (provable in a mathematical way) actually does say that you have to stop at some point and reject further candidates that may be better. Ultimately it's a probability problem (i.e. how sure are you that you have the best one that you could have picked with infinite time and resources, given that you in reality have finite time and finite resources).

Answer (score 1):

In general, recruiting is tending towards volume and speed mainly because the internet makes it so easy for candidates and jobs to match.
A lot of companies are deliberately trying to shorten the recruiting cycle and many will hire someone in less than 2 weeks end to end. In this environment, having an application deadline means missing out on a lot of good candidates who get taken before you even interview them.
Application deadlines seem a throwback to a time when it wasn't always easy for candidates to hear about jobs. You needed to give everyone time to see the ad in a magazine and mail their applications in.
Nowadays, the day a job is posted online, will get 100 applications. Honestly I would question processes of any company with a deadline.

Answer (score 0):

> I was always under the impression that applicants are considered only when the deadline has passed to give everybody a fair chance in successding to the next stages.

You are incorrect. If I get a good candidate, I'm going to hire them - there's no "unfair" here, you had a chance to apply before the deadline, you decided not to apply earlier.

Comment: "you had a chance to apply before the deadline, you decided not to apply earlier" that's not quite true, I decided to put together an application the moment I saw the job advert. To spin this another way, I actually believe that I am a better candidate than the one they hired.

Comment: You could have been looking earlier. Yes, this is slightly harsh but don't try and claim this is somehow "unfair" on you.

Comment: It feels a little bit as though you are attempting to cast me as some sort of victim when what I trying to suggest is that in this instance, this companies process is weighted in favour of those that apply earlier and I would like to know whether it is possible to somehow identifty and avoid these companies but aside from asking them whether they pool candidate before or after the dealine I can't think of anything. I'm interested in this for reasons more than just my application if that helps as I am working for an organisation that is currently developnig one of these recruitment systems.

Comment: @cinameng well, the company needs an employer earlier rather than later, so of course the process is weighted towards people who apply earlier rather than later ;) From the company's perspective, someone who would fit perfectly already applied; why bother waiting for the possibility that someone else will apply later, when we have a guaranteed good candidate now? There is nothing fair or unfair about this; and on average you get the benefit of having applied earlier as often as you get the downside of having applied later.

Comment: @Esther thanks for your reply. I wonder why I should spend a not insignificant amount of time in an evening completing an application for a vacancy that I cannot obtain because the company have already decided to hire somebody else? Why does this have to be viewed from the perspective of what's only in the interest of the employer and not the potential employee? Why doesn't the company have a gated process to ensure that a consistent procedure is followed that can benefit both the employer and the employee? Why does the employer have to fill the vacancy at the earliest possible moment? :)

Comment: @cinameng why should the company adjust their hiring process to suit your application process? :-) They're not optimizing for applicants who later say "I've been rejected, but at least I've been treated fairly." They optimize to fill the vacancy with a fitting candidate, and what the other applicants think isn't really their concern.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner why would it not be in the employers interest to pool candidates fairly?

Comment: @cinameng Because in this market, the good candidate will have another job by the time the "deadline" is reached, and I don't want to miss out on them. Sure, someone better _might_ come along, but also they might not, and I'll take the known good candidate rather than the maybe candidate in the future.

Comment: @PhilipKendall that is a good point though why is it not possible to keep active candidates enaged in the process whilst continuing to prospect for new canidates?

Comment: @cinameng do you not think that a good candidate wouldn't get another offer from a company not so worried about fair processes in the meantime?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere correct we already have customers that are beyond potential as we already have products and we are also building new products. I also believe there could be other ways of building similar products. The fairness issue was nothing to do with the companies values but my own.

Comment: If you want to establish a "fair" recruitment process I would not put so much emphasis on a deadline but instead add wording that quick responses have a better chance of being considered, and take down the ad as soon as a suitable candidate is found (which might not always be the first acceptable one). That way, the probability for possible applicants to write a resume that will certainly be rejected as the position is already filled would be minimized, but you can't completely eliminate it.

Comment: @cinameng Maybe you are the better candidate, but if there is a contract then at this point the other one is considered engaged at this point -- so at this point it'd be very unfair to that new hire, if the company agreed to do an interview with you, because now you're in principle a candidate to *replace* that new hire, rather than simply a candidate to *fill* a vacancy.  Analogously, it'd be kind of like trying to court an engaged woman. Maybe you are indeed the "better candidate" for her, but this'd be quite unfair to the fiancé, since he's already "filled" the position you're applying for.

Comment: Usually there's a start date on an ad. "Starting: ASAP" means send your CV off right now.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of governments or companies with very strict processes, there's a first deadline at the moment the company makes an offer to someone, and the deadline will be reopened if that person doesn't take the offer.

Clever companies use some basic arithmetic: 1. Not having an employee that you want costs money. 2. Processing CVs and the whole hiring process cost money. 3. Taking the second best possible employee instead of the best one costs money. So they will accept CVs and start interviews with people until they find someone who is good enough to do the job (100% necessary), willing to take the job now (100% necessary) and good enough to make it unlikely to find someone much better quickly enough.

The quicker you apply the better your chances. Unless there are really hard  requirements, where the company finds it hard to find anyone good enough. It's very unlikely that there is a deadline. A job can go online, and the perfect candidate reads it the first day, applies, and gets the job. The deadline is when the job is gone.

My strategy: Take a week to see how the market is. Then apply, ordered by the value of the job to me, my chances to get it, and how old the advertisement is (newest first). Try a few outliers just for fun (like I applied for one job in Abu Dhabi, didn't get it. Would have been fun going there for a year or two). Note that when new jobs come in, I apply very quickly, so if I am the right person then I may have the job within a week. At my old company, an ex-colleague contacted me if we had any jobs, I said yes and told my boss, two days later was a job interview, three days later they made a job offer and were too slow.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of people have ideas about recruitment that seem to be based on the recruitment process for staff positions up to the 1970s or so.

By "staff position" I mean something that contrasts with the "workforce", and is a specific technical position in an organisation where the entire function is often covered by one person, or one person and a deputy.

And by "the 1970s", I'm setting a scene in which steady employment in large corporations had become the norm for many, and where there was political policy to have full employment, to encourage workforce planning, and to discourage casual employment and "sweated labour".

Those seeking workforce positions didn't submit written applications - they just rocked up looking ready to work, and talked to the boss for a bit.

Staff candidates, who were of a higher station in life than the general workforce, and would either have a technical education or considerable experience, would form an extremely small pool of recruitment, and they would submit written applications and expect to receive a polite reply either way. An employer would only ever have a small number of these to handle.

Many people, perhaps still informed by the perspective of older relatives, and because they are making an application in writing, and perhaps because their job might be in an office, and because they even have a technical education, think therefore that they are applying to an employer on similar terms to a staff candidate in the 1970s.

In fact, most people are applying to employers on similar terms to dockers and longshoremen in the 1930s. You turn up and put your hand up, and if you're lucky you'll be picked and not one of the hundred others.

In fact, it is only the medium of written communication that prevents most candidates from understanding that they are on the dock amongst a hundred others.

And unlike application letters in the 1970s, which had to be individually penned on paper and then physically posted, sending a CV nowadays is typically as easy as sending bulk junk mail - certainly for the employer, it is like receiving junk mail.

The state even has policies of requiring unemployed workers to send such solicitations to employers, however unseemly and unlikely each application may be.

Therefore for most employers, the submission of any sort of application, is nothing more than a slightly elaborate raising of the hand by one worker amongst a rabble, which is owed nothing in return. You'll be contacted only if needed.

And for those who assume employers should reward candidates who put particular effort into their applications, in fact this is no more desirable to the employer than a 1930s docker submitting his bid for work in writing - it either shows a lack of contact with reality, or ideas well above the station of candidates which the employer is looking for.

This is why most employers, with recruiters brought up since the era of mobile telephones and computers, have ceased imposing long-winded application processes on candidates, because it filters ready and able candidates (especially the experienced who won't dance those tunes), and what makes it to the end is (from the employer's perspective) dross that has high expectations and/or can't get a quicker offer elsewhere.